# How to access contents of current editor cell from a script called in the console?

Tags: spyder, cell

I am generating html files from source files written in python and LaTeX. I want to invoke a script from the console that processes/converts/etc the contents of the current cell in the editor and writes to an html file for preview. How can I access the contents of the current editor cell?